# Broken "rename" feature

Tags: c#, resharper, visual-studio-2015

Lets say I have a variable like this :
[image]
Now when I rename the variable using the shortcut or menus and press enter, it becomes like this:
[image]
The "Show potential fixes" is not due to "Local constant 'renamed' never being used). It asks me to rename the variable again. Why?
I need to click on the "Show potential fixes and choose 'rename variable to renamed'" again. It's very annoying. Is there anyway to fix this?
I just want to use the resharper shortcut and be done with it.

Comment: Note that _show potential fixes_ is not resharper's feature, it's VS2015's Roslyn QuickFix engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in this case for some reason Visual Studio is late to update its code model following the totally legitimate rename operation made by ReSharper.

However, if you ignore Visual Studio's prompt for the second bogus rename and proceed with editing code, Visual Studio will finally understand that a rename has actually occurred and stop asking you to perform it again.

All in all, this is indeed an annoyance but there's an easy workaround: just proceed with editing your code.

We at JetBrains are looking into the problem to see if we can fix it nicely but it's not clear so far if we are able to.

Comment: Thank you. I hope it's fixed soon :)